# Play 2.3 WS withFollowRedirects(true) does not work

Tags: scala, playframework

The following code should post a form to an endpoint (which returns 302) and, after following the redirect, parse the url of the page and return some information from there.

```
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
val requestHolder = WS.url(conf("login.url"))
  .withRequestTimeout(loginRequestTimeOut)
  .withFollowRedirects(true) //This appears to have no effect...

requestHolder.post(getMap(username, password))
  .map(resp =>{
    Logger.debug(resp.status.toString)
    val loginResponse = getResponse(resp)
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

    Logger.debug("Login for the user: "+username+", request took: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.")

    loginResponse
  })
```

The problem is that `.withFollowRedirects(true)` appears to have no effect on the query. The status of the response is 302 and the request does not follow the redirect.

I've gone through the process manually using httpie and following the redirects does lead to the correct page.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` redirection isn't as well supported as `GET` redirection. W3 [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Some browsers don't do that, and just ignore. Have a look also at the `307` status:

> #### 307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1)
>
> In this case, the request should be repeated with another URI; however, future requests should still use the original URI. In contrast to how 302 was historically implemented, the request method is not allowed to be changed when reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST request should be repeated using another POST request.

There is also a discussion about this on [Programmer Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately I have no control over the service I'm posting the form to, so I have to make do with what it provides.

Comment: The rules are enforced by the browsers, you can't change it. You could setup a kind of a proxy to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble with withFollowRedirects and POST.
At some point, while fighting to make things work, I had .withFollowRedirects(false) in my code, then removed it during cleanups & things broke. My current guess is that if this option is not explicitly made false, the default behavior is to follow redirects (302 in my case) with some faulty mechanism. Perhaps the default mechanism uses POST again with same arguments. But in my case, interacting with Google App Script (GAS), one needs to use GET to retrieve JSON output of a POST.
Whatever the mechanism was doing, I was getting 400 with no further diagnostics.
After wasting hours, I realized that .withFollowRedirects(false) was in fact truly needed: it disabled Play's messing with redirects, I was able to see the 302 response & handle the following GET manually with success.